# Обработка нажатия кнопки JavaFX

Tags: java, парсер, javafx

Есть код, парсер веб страницы, в консоль информация выдается в текстовом формате (не в виде html кода), и я хочу, чтобы эта информация появлялась в `textField` при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: И в чём проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: @Bakhuss у меня есть метод, в котором весь код парсера, можно ли как-то реализовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `TextField` есть метод `setText(текст)`, который позволяет установить *текст*. Также следует запретить ввод текста методом `setEditable(false)`

```
String text = // Текст с структурой
           "class Person{\n"+
           "   private int age;\n"+
           "   private String name;\n" +
           "\n"+
           "   public Person(int age, String name) {\n"+
           "       this.age = age;\n"+
           "       this.name = name;\n"+
           "   }\n"+
           "}";

Button setText = new Button("Установить текст");
setText.setOnAction(event -> 
    textField.setText(text));
```

**P.S.** Здесь текст в `textfield` текст не будет структурирован. Чтобы исправить эту проблему надо использовать `TextArea`, у которого есть такие же методы.

Comment: А если есть метод, в котором весь код парсера, можно его тут использовать?

Comment: Сделайте метод, который возвращает String, и используйте textField.setText( method() ); Но информация будет не структурирована.

Comment: @Bakhuss понял, спасибо, а можно ее как-то структурировать?

Comment: @Bakhuss тут проблема в том, что вообще ничего не выдается при нажатие на кнопку, хотя если просто ввести текст (например `textField.setText("abc");`), все работает